# Flatten or remap model in FastAPI (Pydantic)

Tags: python, fastapi, flatten, pydantic

I have set up a simple API in FastAPI. So in my case I have a User table and an Article table. Each user is able to be assigned to multiple articles. There are no limitations. This means, both tables are linked together with a many-to-many field.

When I print out all users, it will be displayed as the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test1",
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "foo",
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "bar",
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "test2",
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "foo",
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

But I want the articles attribute to be flattened. Only the ids of the articles should be visible, without the unwanted dictionary around.

**It should look like this:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "test1",
    "articles": [
      1,
      2,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "test2",
    "articles": [
      1,
    ],
  },
]
```

---

### My files

**schemas.py:**

```
class ArticleBase(BaseModel):
    id: int
    title: str

class UserBase(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username: str
    articles: List[ArticleBase]
```

**main.py:**

```
@app.get("/users/", response_model=List[schemas.UserBase])
def get_users(db: Session = Depends(crud.get_db)):
    return crud.get_users(db)
```

**crud.py:**

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

def get_users(db: Session):
    return db.query(models.User).all()
```

**models.py:**

```
user_article_assoc = Table('user_article_assoc', Base.metadata,
                   Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id')),
                   Column('article_id', Integer, ForeignKey('article.id')))

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    username = Column(String)
    articles = relationship("Article", secondary=user_article_assoc, backref="users")

class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = "article"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will flattern your users into a list of dictionaries, you can easily modify it to convert to other models:

```
flatternedUsers = list(map(lambda u: { 'id' :u.id, 'username': u.username, 'articles': list(map(operator.attrgetter('id'), u.articles)) }, users))
```

You can also use an object-object mapper library for that, such as [object-mapper](https://github.com/marazt/object-mapper) or [odin](https://pythonhosted.org/odin/ref/mapping/classes.html). The benefits of object-object mappers is that if your users now have a new attribute e.g. `birthdate` it will automatically be mapped to same attribute in the flattened user models you want to return, assuming you didn't forget to add `birthdate` attribute to them.